# LSP in OO programming?

Tags: oop

Am I right in thinking the full name of the LSP is the Liskoff Substitution Principle? I'm having trouble finding an [online] source to cite for any information on this... it seems to be a cornerstone of OOP, and yet I'm having trouble finding definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right.  It's spelled Liskov which is probably why you can't find a citation.
Here's the [link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)    One of the better resources regarding this is Robert C. Martin's Agile Software Development Principles Patterns and practices book.

Answer (score 0):

You got the name right.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

It was developed by Barbra Liskov, a professor at MIT.